# Performance characteristics of memory mapped file

Tags: java, linux, memory-mapped-files

Background:

> I have a Java application which does intensive IO on quite large
>   memory mapped files (> 500 MB). The program reads data, writes data,
>   and sometimes does both.
>
> All read/write functions have similar computation complexity.
>
> I benchmarked the IO layer of the program and noticed strange
>   performance characteristics of memory mapped files:
>
> - It performs 90k reads per second (read 1KB every iteration at random position)
> - It performs 38k writes per second (write 1KB every iteration sequentially)
> - It performs 43k writes per second (write 4 bytes every iteration at random position)
> - It performs only 9k read/write combined operation per second (read 12 bytes then write 1KB every iteration, at random position)
>
> The programs on 64-bit JDK 1.7, Linux 3.4.
>
> The machine is an ordinary Intel PC with 8 threads CPU and 4GB physical memory. Only 1 GB was assigned to JVM heap when conducting the benchmark.
>
> If more details are needed, here is the benchmark code: https://github.com/HouzuoGuo/Aurinko2/blob/master/src/test/scala/storage/Benchmark.scala
>
> And here is the implementation of the above read, write, read/write functions: https://github.com/HouzuoGuo/Aurinko2/blob/master/src/main/scala/aurinko2/storage/Collection.scala

So my questions are:

- Given fixed file size and memory size, what factors affect memory mapped file random read performance?
- Given fixed file size and memory size, what factors affect memory mapped file random write performance?
- How do I explain the benchmark result of read/write combined operation? (I was expecting it to perform over 20K iterations per second).

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Show code of how you map the file. 2. Have you checked system load, iostat, all the usual?

Comment: thanks bmargulies. see the latest edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory mapped file performance depends on disk performance, file system type, free memory available for file system cache and read/write block size. The page size on the linux is 4K. So you should expect most performance with 4k read/writes. An access at random position causes page fault if page is not mapped and will pull a new page read. Usually, you want memory mapped file if you want to see the files as a one memory array ( or ByteBuffer in Java ).